# Change RecycleView item width?

Tags: android, adapter

I know there is probably a very simple solution out there, but for the life of me I can't seem to find it. How do I change the width of the RecycleView item? For some reason, it's displaying the first item full width of the parent... It's displaying a lot of white space in between each item.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_wrapper"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Categories"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cats"
                ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CategoryAdapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Category> categories;

public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<Category> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_cat, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Category cat = this.categories.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(cat.getText().toString());
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);
    }
}
```

}

single_cat.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Cat"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_single_shape"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/cat_title"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: What is the xml layout for `single_cat` ?

Comment: show R.layout.single_cat

Comment: Opps sorry. Even when I change the width to be smaller, it's displaying white space until I scroll to the next item.

I've updated the question with the code

Comment: @Jonathon Do you want to change the width of all items or just a single item?

Comment: How is your `RecyclerView` added to _its_ parent?

Comment: @Ben P, not sure what you mean I'm sorry. I'd like to display the items close together, without the huge whitespace. It's showing only one item and a huge amount of whitespace. Then when I swipe, it'll show the other item.

Comment: Your RecyclerView is in some other layout. Is it the only view in a layout passed to `setContentView()`? Is it inflated at runtime? Is it `<include>`-ed? Do you call `new RecyclerView(this)`? How do you get your RecyclerView into your app?

Comment: I've updated the question again. I've set the layout to horizontal using this in my MainActivity.class:
```
categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
        cats.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after 2 days and looking all over the internet, I figured it out myself.

Make sure your ***Constraint Layout*** is ***wrap_content***. This was the issue all along!

Answer (score 1):

1)in your fragment do :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

2)for recyclerView single item .xml do :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"

android:layout_height="50dp"

android:layout_margin="4dp">


<TextView

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3) and change RecyclerView to :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_wrapper"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="Categories"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:id="@+id/cats"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would change single cat to

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@drawable/cat_single_shape"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/cat_title"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not wanting the item to fill the parent.

Comment: please clarify what you want.

Comment: I'm wanting at least 3 items to be visible on the screen before swiping to see more